# Who uses AdMob in a MonoTouch iPhone app?

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios, admob

Who uses AdMob in a MonoTouch iPhone app?

The current sdk we got for admob is admob_iphone_sdk_20100908.tar.gz

It has two lib files, but only the NoThumb file is usefull due to the well known bug in the Apple linker:

```
libAdMobNoThumb.a (2.464.412 bytes, created on 16 september 2010 at 14:41)
```

When we link a test app (just a freshly generated iPhone Windows-based Project, with no changes whatsoever) using following extra flags:

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lAdMobNoThumb -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libAdMobNoThumb.a"
```

mtouch fails miserably with 
    mtouch failed with no output (1)

(We use the -force_load option instead of the -ObjC option, as indicated in the note at the end of:

```
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html)
```

The MT_SampleAdMob.zip test project available from the blog at

```
http://sabonrai.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/monotouch-binding-for-admob/
```

contains two older NoThumb libraries:

```
libAdMobDeviceNoThumb3_0.a (539.288 bytes, created 15 jan 2010 at 03:26)
libAdMobSimulator3_0.a (488.464 bytes, created 5 september 2009)
```

When using the libAdMobDeviceNoThumb3_0.a library with following gcc_flags:

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lAdMobDeviceNoThumb3_0 -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libAdMobDeviceNoThumb3_0.a"
```

the build succeeds and an app is generated.

We have not yet integrated any of the admob stuff in this app, so we are not stating anything about admob functionality. Merely about being able to link with a library, which seems essential before even trying to use its functionality.

We are frustrated by the fact that the official library does not link, where an older version does link. Also, the size difference is considerable: the official file has swollen with a factor of 4.5!

So if anyone out there uses admob in a monotouch app, please supply any relevant information so that we can proceed with our app.

TIA,

Mollyke.

Comment: This sounds like a post that belongs on the AdMob site directly.

Comment: Well we've mailed them about this too. Just desperate to hear some positive news about this. If one googles around, there's several people struggling with this, so we thought it would be good to have an open forum about it.

Comment: Add -v -v -v before -gcc_flags so we can see the verbose output and help you with your issue.

Comment: This pinpointed the problem. The admob library also uses an objective c source TouchJSON part. I did not bother with it yet, thinking that It'd be best to first try to solve the linker problem. However the -v -v -v revealed that TouchJSON was the cause:

Comment: Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONSerializer in libAdMobNoThumb.a(AdMobAd.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONSerializer in libAdMobNoThumb.a(AdMobWebView.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONSerializer in libAdMobNoThumb.a(AdMobFlexWebView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONDeserializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libAdMobNoThumb.a(AdMobOpener.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libAdMobNoThumb.a(AdMobSearchViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libAdMobNoThumb.a(AdMobAd.o)

Comment: Sorry for the unexpected flowing. I'll try to generate a library from these objc sources, so that I can conclude it in the link.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271126/monotouch-binding-for-touchjson

Comment: I'm not sure why you opened a second question for the same issue, but I answered it there.

Answer (score 1):

Since many people will find this question, you can use the up to date monotouch bindings for admob posted on github here https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds

Here is an example of how to use it and how to suscribe to its events

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            var ad = new GADBannerView(new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), GADBannerView.GAD_SIZE_300x250))
            {
                AdUnitID = "Use Your AdMob Id here",
                RootViewController = this

            };

            ad.DidReceiveAd += delegate 
            {
                this.View.AddSubview(ad);
                Console.WriteLine("AD Received");
            };

            ad.DidFailToReceiveAdWithError += delegate(object sender, GADBannerViewDidFailWithErrorEventArgs e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
            };

            ad.WillPresentScreen += delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("showing new screen");
            };

            ad.WillLeaveApplication += delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("I will leave application");
            };

            ad.WillDismissScreen += delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("Dismissing opened screen");
            };

            Console.Write("Requesting Ad");
            ad.LoadRequest(new GADRequest());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the AdMob library works as soon as the TouchJSON library is also linked into the app through the gcc_flags.